MockMVC standaloneSetup builder is giving error in spring webmvc version 6.1.13
I Am trying the below code which used to work earlier but due to a high 'PATH TRANVERSAL' vulnerability in older versions of spring webmvc, i had to upgrade to latest version of spring webmvc dependency which is 6.1.13 in the pom file. But after the changes below code started breaking :
 @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController)
                .build();
    }

It gives below error when I try do mvn install:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod.createWithValidateFlags()'

Also, when i run the application it gives below error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed

I checked if i can find anything in the documentation but i am not sure what is the right direction for me now:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/webtestclient.html#webtestclient-controller-config

You are using Spring Boot which means you shouldn't do manual setup and of all things never update versions of individual dependencies (what you did) as that will lead to incompatibilities.

You should probably use AutoConfigureMockMvc to automatically configure your MockMvc
